# Cascaded summation function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am dealing with writing an equation in matlab which has a cascaded form as attached in the figure.
[image]

How can I solve it using symsum? If  the limits were not going to inifinity, I could have used loop, but because of infinity I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer

We can use cascaded function as

```
syms m,k
S3 = symsum(symsum(f, m, 0, k), k,0,inf) %Where f is the function
```